# Flexboxの要素の大きさを画面サイズによらず固定したい

Tags: html, css

Flexboxで`justify-content`や`align-items`を使うと簡単に中の要素を中央揃えさせることができますが、画面サイズによって、要素の大きさが変わってしまいます

これを固定することはできますか?

flexboxを要素を簡単に中央揃えできるbox(画面サイズによって伸び縮みしてほしくない)として使いたいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか?

`width`や`height`を使っても上手くいきませんでした

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

とすると画面幅によらず、`width`に従います。(高さに関しては未検証です。)

`width`でなく[`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)を使うのならば[`flexショートハンド`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/flex)を使って、

```css
flex: 0 0 10em;
```

の様に指定する事も出来ます。

```css
div{
  border-style: solid;
}
.box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-color: blue;
}
.item-by-width{
  width: 10em;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0; 
  border-color: orange;
}
.item-by-basis{
  flex-basis: 10em;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0; 
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item-by-width">アイテム(width)</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="item-by-basis">アイテム(basis)</div>
</div>
```